# How to use inner join for 3 columns with condition MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have 2 tables
in table sample1 have key1 and key2 ....
in table sample2 have tey1 and tey2 and tey3 ....

i want join tables with this condition
1_  key1 = tey1
Or
2_  key2 = tey2 or key2 = tey3

**and if key1 = tey1 dontcheck key2 = tey2 or key2 = tey3**

my querie is :

```
Select *
from sample1 inner join sample2 
on  sample1.key1 = sample2.tey1 OR  sample1.key2 = sample2.tey2 OR sample1.key2 = sample2.tey3
```

but it's too slow and i think not optimal
Each table has more than 100,000 rows and datatypes of the key1,2,3 and tey1,2, is Text

how can i use join optimal?

Comment: How big are the tables?  What indexes do you have?  What are the datatypes of the key1,2,3 and tey1,2,3?

Comment: @RickJames 
Each table has more than 100,000 rows
 datatypes of the key1,2,3 and tey1,2,3 is Text

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect justified by reference to authoritative documentation or ask re your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask re the former 1st because misconceptions in the former will get in the way of understanding the latter. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do. [ask] [Help] Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: Do they need to be `TEXT`?  Or would it be OK to use `VARCHAR(100)` or some other reasonably-sized varchar.?

Answer (score -1):

select s1.*,s2.*
from sample1 as s1, sample2 as s2
where s1.key1 = s2.tey1 OR  s1.key2 = s2.tey2 OR s1.key2 = s2.tey3

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).